# Fetch Data from a Wix Database through http request

Tags: dart, httprequest, velo, flutter-http, dart-http

I created a database with Wix that has several different types of content like Strings, images, addresses and more.I want to use the information from the WIX database for an app(made with **Flutter** and **Dart**); simply portraying the information in a ListView but it seems the data doesnt reach the app.

I created the necessary function on Wix to make the database accessible for third parties and tested it with Postman. When i make the request with this Url (https://daudadmin.editorx.io/acteeventpage/_functions/regions) it works fine and Postman returns the items with all the information as JSON.

Now when i use the Url in my app code; it just returns a blank page. That is the code i use currently:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final url = 'https://daudadmin.editorx.io/acteeventpage/_functions/regions';
  var _postsJson = [];

  void fetchData() async {
    try {
      final response = await get(Uri.parse(url));
      final jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body) as List;

      setState(() {
        _postsJson = jsonData;
      });
    } catch (err) {
      //handle error here with error message
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    fetchData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: _postsJson.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, i) {
              final post = _postsJson[i];
              return Text("Title: ${post["title"]}");
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the line causing your error

```
final jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body) as List;
```

The data being returned from the endpoint is a Map and not a List.

```
{
  "items": [
    {},
    ...
  ],
}
```

To access the list, try accessing the items property of the map by changing the declaration to

```
final jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body)["items"] as List;
```